# XSLT task using different stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, ant

First, excuse my bad english.

Here is the problem: I have a directory `stylesheet-dir` where I have undefined number of `xsl` files, each with different name of course. 
What I need is the xslt task to do transformations as many as the files in the directory are. So far so good, this should do the job:

```
    <target name="do-report">
        <xslt basedir="${stylesheet-dir}" destdir="${output_dir}" style="stylesheet.xsl" force="true">
            <classpath location="${processor_path}"/>
        </xslt>
    </target>
```

The problem ^^above^^, is that `stylesheet.xsl` is same for each transformation.
I need the stylesheet to be coherent each transformation. And the funniest part is that the input file and the stylesheet shall be the same.
I was searching for workaround trough the internet with no success though. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ant is not a scripting language and only has limited support for iterating over filesets, for example the [apply task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html). In these situations I reach for an embedded groovy script, which is capable of calling other ANT tasks.

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── src
│   ├── xml
│   │   ├── file1.xml
│   │   ├── file2.xml
│   │   └── file3.xml
│   └── xsl
│       ├── file1.xsl
│       └── file2.xsl
└── target
    ├── xsl1
    │   ├── file1.xml
    │   ├── file2.xml
    │   └── file3.xml
    └── xsl2
        ├── file1.xml
        ├── file2.xml
        └── file3.xml
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <available classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" property="groovy.installed"/> 

  <target name="build" depends="install-groovy">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>

    <fileset id="xslfiles" dir="src/xsl"  includes="*.xsl"/>
    <fileset id="xmlfiles" dir="src/xml"  includes="*.xml"/>

    <groovy>
      def count = 1
      project.references.xslfiles.each { xsl ->
        project.references.xmlfiles.each { xml ->
          def xslfile = new File(xsl.toString())
          def xmlfile = new File(xml.toString())
          def outfile = new File("target/xsl${count}", xmlfile.name)

          ant.xslt(force:true, style:xslfile, in:xmlfile, out:outfile)
        }
        count++
     }
    </groovy>
  </target>

  <target name="install-groovy" unless="groovy.installed">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/groovy-all.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.5/groovy-all-2.4.5.jar"/>
    <fail message="groovy has been installed. Run the build again"/>
  </target>

</project>
```